# TCP Socket Server send message

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, socketserver

I am trying to implement a threaded TCP server using socketserver as documented here.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example

I am trying to get it to connect to other servers and send messages, but I can't do `self.server.socket.connect((host, port))` as it keeps returning `OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied`. I understand that this might be because the socket is not configured, but printing it gives `<socket.socket fd=792, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=(host, port)>`, which seems to be fine?

```
class Component:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server = ThreadedTCPServer((host, port), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
        self.server.socket.connect((host, port))

        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
        # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
        server_thread.daemon = True
        server_thread.start()
        print("Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name)
```

Trying to create a separate `self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` raises `OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted` even when I set `allow_reuse_address = True` in `ThreadedTCPServer`.

Comment: The server part in TCP is the one that accepts connection, not the one that actively connects. BTW: Is it relevant that you're using threads?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Currently running the server on threads, how do actively connect to other servers then?

Comment: You don't. The server offers a service and for that it accepts incoming client connections. That is the point of a server. If your program at some point needs to make a connection to another server, it then acts as a client. Still, your program may do that, but not the server component within your program.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I guess the question is how can I make a client and server share the same port, and if there is a way to do it with the socketserver framework